# What's the probability that 3 out of 23 people will share the same birthday?

Tags: statistics

The probability that 2 out of 23 people will share the same birthday is slightly higher than 50%, and that is the famous Birthday Paradox. However, what is the probability that 3 out of 23 people will? I have, like [I have written in this article about something distantly related to that](https://flatassembler.github.io/Karasica), estimated numerically using Monte Carlo method that it is around 1.26%, and that the probability that 4 out of 23 people will share the same birthday is around 0.018%. However, I am interested whether there is a general formula for that, and, if so, what it is.

Comment: Do you mean at least three?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes.